# Postgresql update in loop with nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loops, async-await, pg

I need update postgresql table records in loop.
I write this code:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
var slug = require('slug');

const credentials = {
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'dev',
  password: 'secret',
  port: 5432,
};

const pool = new Pool(credentials);

async function getEditions() {
  const sql = `SELECT * FROM editions`;
  return pool.query(sql);
}

async function updateEdition(id, slug) {
  const values = [id, slug];
  try {
    const text = `UPDATE editions SET slug = $2 WHERE id = $1`;
    await pool.query(text, values);
    console.log('Updated');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

(async () => {
  const getEditionsResult = await getEditions();

  getEditionsResult.rows.forEach(async (e) => {
    await updateEdition(e.id, slug(e.name));
  });

  await pool.end();
})();
```

But data not updated in forEach loop.
If i try update one record, it's ok.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `for..loop` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: Yes. Problem was in forEach loop